# Download a file with name including special characters from FTP server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I tried to download files, but all files with special character cannot be recognized. Other files can be downloaded, while file named `asdf#code@.pdf` cannot be downloaded.

Error:

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

In local, the file with correct name is created, but it is empty. The same thing happens on JPG files with `#` inside of the file names. how can I let them be recognized?

```
//Download the file from remote path on FTP to local path
private static void Download(string remotePath, string localPath)
{
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    try
    {
        reqFTP = GetWebRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile, remotePath);
        FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Create);

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long cl = response.ContentLength;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        ftpStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("File Download: ", remotePath + " is downloaded completely");
        logWriter.WriteLog("File Download: ", remotePath + " is downloaded completely, status " + response.StatusDescription);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logWriter.WriteLog("File Download: ", "Cannot download file from " + remotePath + " to " + localPath + "\n" + " Erro Message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}//End Download

//Web request for FTP
static public FtpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string method, string uri)
{
    Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);

    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        var reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        reqFTP.Method = method;
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userId, password);
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
        return reqFTP;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logWriter.WriteLog("Get Web Request: ","Cannot connect to " + uri + "\n" + "Error: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be recognized"? What error do you get? What is the output when you try to get a directory listing of that FTP directory with `WebMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory`?

Comment: Other files can be downloaded, while file named "asdf#code@.pdf" cannot be downloaded. Erro: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Comment: the file name is correct in WebMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory.

Comment: @Quentin: You're getting an error thrown by the web-server. It has nothing to do with this code. If you own this web-server then you should start looking into that. I dont know what the naming restrictions are for different file systems but i suspect the issue is that the file system the server is running on and/or the file system the code is running on does not support files with those characters in their name.

Comment: @caesay:I tried the ftp server in my company (as test) and one in guest company. Neither of the two can download the file with "#" "@". I am supposed to download files from guest company. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: @Quentin: Can you download the file using another FTP client (i.e. not your program)?

Comment: @Heinzi:Sorry for replying late. Yes. Actually, if I change the file to a regular name, it works. So I am pretty sure there is something I can do with the file name or URI.

Comment: @Quentin: My question was aimed at something different: If you keep the "strange" file name and you use a "regular" FTP client (e.g. Internet Explorer or something else), can you download the file?

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes, IE and Filezilla are able to download it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *might* be by design: According to [the URI standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), `#` is not a valid character in a URI. Thus, `ftp://someServer/somePath/intro_to_c#.pdf` is *not* a valid URI.

What you could do is to properly escape the file name when *creating* the URI:

```
string baseUri = "ftp://someServer/somePath/";
string file = "intro_to_c#.pdf";
string myUri = baseUri + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file);
// yields ftp://someServer/somePath/intro_to_c%23.pdf
```

Alternatively, you could use the UriBuilder class, which handles escaping properly:

```
Uri myUri = new UriBuilder("ftp", "someServer", 21, "somePath/intro_to_c#.pdf");
// yields ftp://someServer:21/somePath/intro_to_c%23.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I add some code and fixed it. Use hexEscape to escape "#" but it is not decent. Any one have idea to escape special characters in URI?

```
    // Get the request using a specific URI 
    static public FtpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string method, string uri)
    {
        Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);

        **if (serverUri.ToString().Contains("#"))
        {
            serverUri = new Uri(serverUri.ToString().Replace("#", Uri.HexEscape('#')));
        }**
        Console.WriteLine(serverUri.ToString());
        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            var reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
            reqFTP.Method = method;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userId, password);
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            return reqFTP;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logWriter.WriteLog("Get Web Request: ", "Cannot connect to " + uri + "\n" + "Error: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```